# replace the outlier value from multiple columns based on different condition using pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to find the outlier in multiple columns at a time and replace the outlier value with some other value based on two conditions.
sample dataset:

```
day phone_calls received
1   11  11
2   12  12
3   10  0
4   13  12
5   170 2
6   9   9
7   67  1
8   180 150
9   8   1
10  10  10
```

find out the outlier range, let's say the range is (8-50), then replace the value: if the column value is less than 8 then replace with 8, and if greater than 50 then replace with 50.
Please help I am new to pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
df = df.set_index('day').clip(8,50)
print (df)
     phone_calls  received
day                       
1             11        11
2             12        12
3             10         8
4             13        12
5             50         8
6              9         9
7             50         8
8             50        50
9              8         8
10            10        10
```

Or similar with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) select all columns without first:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].clip(8,50)
print (df)
   day  phone_calls  received
0    1           11        11
1    2           12        12
2    3           10         8
3    4           13        12
4    5           50         8
5    6            9         9
6    7           50         8
7    8           50        50
8    9            8         8
9   10           10        10
```

EDIT: You can specify columns in `list`:

```
cols = ['phone_calls','received']
df[cols] = df[cols].clip(8,50)
print (df)
   day  phone_calls  received
0    1           11        11
1    2           12        12
2    3           10         8
3    4           13        12
4    5           50         8
5    6            9         9
6    7           50         8
7    8           50        50
8    9            8         8
9   10           10        10
```

Comment: can we get the percentage of change in columns, I mean after changing the outlier values, can we get the percentage of change?

Comment: Actually, outlier value is different for different columns, as per the function it is changing the value in every column, it should change the value in the specific column, let's say only on "received" column.

Comment: @Sidhartha what is expected output?

Comment: the second answer you gave is my expected output, means (8,50) should be replaced only on selected the column, let's say only on "received" or "phone_calls".

Comment: @Sidhartha - I understand now, please check last edit.